# Add Header and Footer for AvroIO Writer

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We have a requirements to add a header and footer to a output avro file, but seems like the SDK doesn't support it. For TextIO writer, it seems to have that capability `withHeader` and `withFooter`.

That been said, what's the best way to do it without creating a separate pipeline? I tried add another step after the writer, but seems like the pipeline assumed to be ended after the writer.

Comment: Doing some research I came around this [github](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/1918/) pull request that might answer your query within avroIO where it outlines how you can make use of headers and footers.

Comment: Is this a new file format? Is this some header/footer that exists within the existing Avro file format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution by extending `FileBasedSink`.

```java
public class CustomAvroSink extens FileBasedSink{
...
 @Override
  public WriteOperation<DestinationT, GenericRecord> createWriteOperation() {
    return new CustomAvroWriteOperation(this, this.genericRecords, this.header, this.footer);
....
  }

private static class CustomAvroWriteOperation<DestinationT, OutputT> extends
      WriteOperation<DestinationT, OutputT> {

    private final DynamicAvroDestinations<?, DestinationT, OutputT> dynamicDestinations;
    private final boolean genericRecords;
    private final OutputT header;
    private final OutputT footer;

    private CustomAvroWriteOperation(HeaderFooterAvroSink<?, DestinationT, OutputT> sink,
        boolean genericRecords, OutputT header, OutputT footer) {
      super(sink);
      this.dynamicDestinations = sink.getDynamicDestinations();
      this.genericRecords = genericRecords;
      this.header = header;
      this.footer = footer;
    }

    public Writer<DestinationT, OutputT> createWriter() throws Exception {
      return new CustomAvroWriter<>(this, this.dynamicDestinations, this.genericRecords,
          this.header, this.footer);
    }
  }

...
  private static class CustomAvroWriter<DestinationT, OutputT> extends
      Writer<DestinationT, OutputT> {
   @Override
    protected void writeHeader() throws Exception {
      if (this.header != null) {
        this.dataFileWriter.append(this.header);
      }
    }

  @Override
    protected void writeFooter() throws Exception {
      if (this.footer != null) {
        this.dataFileWriter.append(this.footer);
      }
    }
 }
}
```

Then I can just do `myPCollection.apply("header footer",WriteFiles.to(new CustomAvroSink(...header, footer...)))`